# Is "winningest" an acceptable word? What does it mean?

Tags: word-usage

On [this article](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/691061.html), I came across the use of a word `winningest`.

> It isn't a surprise that the experts still reckon that when in doubt, think about it and then decide to bat anyway, for that used to be the **winningest** strategy when most of them played the game.

Is this an acceptable word? If not, then is there a single word or phrase to replace it? (As opposed to reordering the words to `strategy most likely to lead to a win`.

I looked around on the internet and found out that it is an informal word, which means `one with most wins`. However, in the above context, it seems to mean `one most likely to lead to a win`. Is this article using the word wrongly (informal as it may be), or did I interpret in wrong?

Further, is it also acceptable to use `winninger` similarly?

Comment: In Ireland (near the land of Collins), winningest is never used as the folk there have never won anything in their lives...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on context.

**No**, in most formal contexts you should not use this word.

**No**, you should not use this word even in informal contexts outside the US.  It is an Americanism (although it appears to a lesser extent in other countries).

**Yes**, it's fine in certain informal contexts.  It's particularly used **in the discussion of sports**, as in the page you link to.  It's easily understood and surprisingly common in this context.

And I think you've got the meaning right.  Even with well-established words, meaning tends to be fairly flexible.  With a word like this that is only accepted in some informal contexts, meaning is more flexible still.  It's not so much a matter of "right" and "wrong", but "Did they communicate successfully?"  And since you understood, it seems that they did!

And **no**, don't say **winninger*.  It's understandable (at least in certain contexts), and you can say it if you really want to, but even people who say *winningest* don't say *winninger*.

Comment: +1, especially for the interesting origin lesson (both here and in your comments with Matt above :)). I don't know that I quite endorse "winninger" as *understandable*, but can agree to disagree ;) I understood it in the question because it was proposed as an offshoot of *winningest* (which I'd never heard before, but got from the context of the OP's quote). Had I heard it "in the wild", I'd probably have said something like "What kind of bird are we talking about now?" ;)

Comment: @WendiKidd I'd like to imagine that a winninger looks something like a [plover](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:Sieweczka.jpg) :-)

Answer (score 8):

*It's a [perfectly cromulent word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqW5XTuRp_8)* :)

**Seriously though, it's not a common usage English word, and I've never heard it said in British English. It's also very informal (and sounds uneducated to my ears) even in American English. Try to avoid its use in normal text or speech.**

It *is*, however a real word, as defined thus:

> adjective (informal)
>
> having achieved the most success in competition.

And as you have seen, it *is* used in American English, although not very much.

[image]

Contrast, the British English graph:

[image]

So the simple answer to your question is ***yes***. *Winningest* is a word. But my advice would be not to use it. A better way of phrasing would be

> It isn't a surprise that the experts still reckon that when in doubt, think about it and then decide to bat anyway, for that used to be the strategy ***that was most likely to win*** when most of them played the game.
>
> It isn't a surprise that the experts still reckon that when in doubt, think about it and then decide to bat anyway, for that used to be the strategy ***that won the most*** when most of them played the game.

or even just:

> It isn't a surprise that the experts still reckon that when in doubt, think about it and then decide to bat anyway, for that used to be the ***best*** strategy when most of them played the game.

And whilst ***winningest*** is pretty bad - ***winninger*** doesn't appear to be a word at all. So don't use it.

Comment: *Winningest* is older than the internet.  As sports jargon, it goes back to at least the 50s.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently so. I'm just trying to find out where it originated and then I'll change my answer. It's not acceptable British English - at least not where I'm from :)

Comment: Ah. First use is 1972. It is a recent American bastardization :)

Comment: [COHA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/) has cites back in the 50s.  (There are a couple stray occurrences before that, but they don't fit the pattern of sports jargon.)

Comment: Being neither American, nor taking any interest in American sports, I can honestly say I have *never* heard it used seriously by any native speaker, at all, my entire life, in any context. It might be a word, but it's not a good one for a learner to use. Even so, I have updated my answer

Comment: I confirmed that it was an Americanism using GloWbE back when I wrote my answer.  I'm mostly familiar with it because I know other people who are into sports, although I know next to nothing about them myself :-)

Comment: The word gets used quite a bit in sports, as in: _He is the [winningest coach](http://www.google.com/#q=%22winningest+coach%22&safe=off) in franchise history_. That could mean he's racked up the most wins, or amassed the highest winning percentage, depending on who is doing the analysis.

Comment: @J.R.: But only in America :)

Comment: @Matt - And sometimes [India](http://www.outlookindia.com/article.aspx?208532).

Comment: "It might be a word, but it's not a good one for a learner to use." Agree. I (also British) would assume it was a mistake if I heard it.

Answer (score 3):

It is an Americanism, perhaps a slang! Most used by U.S. sport commentators, it simply sounds wrong and it is wrong to use although it is unfortunately now a searchable word by Google! It is also awkward to pronounce. Not used in British English.